# Google Places API - Enable CORS - Ionic 2 + Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, wkwebview

I am using the Http object to request data from Google Places API. Everything it was working ok, but after install the WkWebView Plugin and I am having the CORS issue.

Is there any way to enable cors without a server? Or maybe I can use jsonp? Any example of how to do it?

Here is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class PlacesService {

  // Geolocation object
    locator: any = null;

  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  search(place: string) {

    console.log('searchPlace', place, encodeURIComponent(place));

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=MYAPIKEY&query=' + encodeURIComponent(place))
      .map( res => res.json() )
      .subscribe( data => {
        resolve(data);
      });

    }); // Promise
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: in your index.html did you add content-security-policy tag ? If you haven't yet, try adding it. [An example can be found here](http://people.mozilla.org/~bsterne/content-security-policy/details-1.0.html)

Comment: No, its not working, Maybe you know how to use jsonp in Angular 2?

Comment: It worked for me when I added to my app that called Twitter and Stackoverflow apis. No, I am aware of how to use jsonp in Angular2.

Comment: Inside an WkWebView? I think its not possible :S